# MongoDB : How to compare object values to array values and add a field in this object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB with this structure:

[image]

**Registration** is an array & it's Object look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e844235ead49b7ff33962d3"), 
        "date" : "2-jul", 
        "firstname" : "John", 
        "lastname" : "Doe", 
        "email" : "john@doe.com", 
        "education" : "University", 
        "gender" : "male", 
        "age" : "32", 
        "workshop" : [2,3,6]
}
```

And **known** looks like this:

```
"known" : [
        "tina@hotmail.com", 
        "sanders@hotmail.com", 
        "kyrana@hotmail.com"
]
```

How can you check if `registrations.email` exists in `known`? If it exist how can you add a field to registrations: `emailIsKnown: true` or `emailIsKnown: false`?

I've tried different variations of filter, replaceRoot, lookUp with pipelines and mergeObject. But I can't seem to figure out how to only accomplish a minimum of comparing results or adding a field to the registrations object.

Comment: Is registrations an array of objects or an object ?

Comment: @whoami an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Re-create 'registration' array field */
  {
    $addFields: {
      registration: {
        $map: {
          input: "$registration", // Iterate on 'registration' array
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: ["$$this.email", "$known"] }, // Check if current object's email exists in 'known' array
              { $mergeObjects: [{ emailIsKnown: true }, "$$this"] }, // If Yes, add new field with true to existing Object
              { $mergeObjects: [{ emailIsKnown: false }, "$$this"] } // If No, add new field with false to existing Object
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6sI48ut53LT)

Comment: Thanks whoami, it's really nice to have an extended example like yours including the this keyword, map and a condition. I'm gonna have a lot of fun with this from now on forwards. Your solution worked instantly, thank you!